# how to prompting the user to enter a correct value after he already entered a wrong(out of range) value?

Tags: java, range, prompt

```
System.out.println("Enter the first test score:");

double test1 = input.nextInt();

if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");

System.out.println("Enter the second test score:");

double test2 = input.nextInt();

if (!(test2 >= 0  && test2 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a number between 0 and 100 .");
```

If i prompt the user to enter a value for test1  and its nor in the specific range, how do i prompt him again to enter a correct value ?. now if i run the and enter a bad value the "This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a number between 0 and 100 " msg would show up but it goes straight to test2. i tried to do this

```
System.out.println("Enter the first test score:");

double test1 = input.nextInt();

if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
double test1 = input.nextInt();
```

but i get an error msg.
Do i have to use a loop and if so how?

Comment: Use a while loop, something like `while(!(test2 >= 0  && test2 <= 100))`, keep asking for a new input.

Comment: `but i get an error msg.` what does that error message say?

Comment: Loop it and use continue if not matched and break if matched and got to test2 condition.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are declaring `test1` twice.

```
double test1 = input.nextInt();

if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
-->  double test1 = input.nextInt(); //Look at this line
```

Just try following:
double test1 = input.nextInt();

```
if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
test1 = input.nextInt();
```

For even cleaner code use following method:

```
public double getValue(){
        double test1=input.nextInt();
        if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100)){
            return getValue();
        }else{
            return test1;
        }
    }
```

Above code would keep taking user inputs unless the input is correct according to `!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are declaring test1 twice, second - you can use loop

```
    double test1 = input.nextInt();
    while(!(test1 >= 0 && test1 <= 100))
    {
        System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
        /*double */test1 = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
double test1 = input.nextInt();
while(!(test1 >= 0 && test1 <= 100)) {
     System.out.println("Enter a valid number"); 
     test1.nextInt();
}
```

The idea is to prompt the user ***until*** he enters a valid input. If you use simple if-statements or a fixed for-loop you'll end up asking only for a fixed amount for the right value.

Another thing you should keep in mind is:

```
if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
double test1 = input.nextInt(); //There is no need to declare test1 again. Remove double
```

will be compiled as

```
if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100))
     System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");

test1 = input.nextInt(); //This is not part of the if!!!!
```

so you have to use brackets like

```
if (!(test1 >= 0  && test1 <= 100)) {
    System.out.println("This is out of the acceptable range, please enter a  number between 0 and 100 .");
    test1 = input.nextInt(); 
}
```